# if statement with two conditions in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I am writing a simple console program to help myself and some fellow geology students with rock sample analysis. Our lecturer provided us with a flow chart that helps to specify the characteristics of the sample. I am attempting to make this into a console program.

My question is whether it is possible for the if statement on line 9 to take two conditions and if so have I written it correctly?

```
   def igneous_rock(self):
    print "Welcome to IgneousFlowChart"
    print "Assuming you are looking at an igneous rock, please choose the "
    print "option which best describes the sample:"
    print "1. Coherent 2. Clastic"

    choice1 = raw_input("> ")

    if choice1 = '1', 'Coherent':    # this is the line in question!
        return 'coherent'
    elif choice1 = '2', 'Clastic':
        return 'clastic'
    else:
        print "That is not an option, sorry."
        return 'igneous_rock'
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You may never have more or less than one condition in an `if` or `while` statement.

Comment: `if choice1 = '1'`, if nothing else, is using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equivalence operator (`==`). You can chain them with `if choice1 == '1' or choice1 == 'Coherent'`, or you can use `in` as in the other excellent answers.

Comment: your code hs wrong syntax, for comparison you should use '==' operator, '=' is an assigment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct the list of elements for which the `if` condition should evaluate to Truthy, and then use `in` operator like this, to check if `choice1`'s value is in that list of elements, like this

```
if choice1 in ['1', 'Coherent']:
...
elif choice1 in ['2', 'Clastic']:
...
```

Instead of lists, you can use tuples as well

```
if choice1 in ('1', 'Coherent'):
...
elif choice1 in ('2', 'Clastic'):
...
```

If the list of items to be checked is huge, then you can construct a set like this

```
if choice1 in {'1', 'Coherent'}:
...
elif choice1 in {'2', 'Clastic'}:
...
```

`set`s offer faster lookup than lists or tuples. You can create `set`s with [set literal syntax `{}`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes)

Comment: why list instead of tuple?

Comment: Don't the curly braces create dictionaries? I think you use Set([..]) to create a set?

Comment: @BenEchols: Curly braces with a comma-separated sequence of items inside create a set.

Comment: Note that building a set on every run of the `if` to test containment likely won't be any faster than using a tuple. In Python 3.2, they added an optimization where `in` tests against sets of compile-time constants use a pre-built frozenset, but that doesn't happen in Python 2.

Comment: @user2357112 I just checked that, Thanks man :) I think peephole optimizer does that.

Answer (score 2):

```
if choice1 in ('1', 'Coherent'):
```